# Can I pass SSH session from programming language to system terminal?

Tags: ssh, terminal

I work with 100+ servers, each of them having different SSH credentials, with passwords that change quite often. The list of the servers and credentials is stored in our company's internal wiki. Every time I need to connect to one of the servers, I have to look to the wiki and copy-paste the information in order to put together the connection string for the system terminal.

As I have to repeat this process dozens of times a day, I'm looking for a way to optimize this routine.

Using any programming language, I can easily extract the information and create the connection string. But after this, I would like to somehow create a SSH session, using the generated connection string and have the SSH session available in the system terminal, which is in my case the Ubuntu terminal.

**Do you know of any programming language or method that would allow running custom login to gather connection information and then use it to launch SSH session in system terminal?**

Comment: You can write the string to a bash script and run the script. Why isn't the information in this format to begin with?

Comment: Did you hear about a program called ssh pass already? That would seem the simplest solution to me.

Comment: @MadPhysicist As stated, the information is not static. It is changing and because of this, it is stored in the wiki, which can be reached by many employees. I believe I could get the information using Bash, but I would have to overcome authentication, figure out html parsing and many other obstacles, which are definitely easier to solve in higher programming languages.

Comment: @Ferrybig I believe sshpass program can only be used to programmatically provide the password, not the whole connection string.

Comment: Python can do this for you. The output of the python script would be a temporary bash script. Python could even run it for you in a subprocess. Alternatively, you could write a bash script to trigger the python script, get the file name that it creates, and source it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Mad Physicist hinted, it can be done by putting the generated ssh command to Bash script and running this script using Python.

Bash script:

```
user@machine:~/$ cat ssh.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ssh remote-user@10.10.10.1
```

*The bash script must be executable in order for this demonstration to work.*

```
user@machine:~/$ chmod +x ssh.sh
```

Python script:

```
user@machine:~/$ cat ssh.py 
import subprocess

subprocess.call("./ssh.sh", shell=True)
```

Execution:

```
user@machine:~/$ python ssh.py 
remote-user@10.10.10.1's password: 
Last login: Mon Jun 17 07:31:45 2019 from 10.10.10.2

 Remote Server [~]
07:35:31 remote-user@remote-server $ echo hello
hello

 Remote Server [~]
07:35:41 remote-user@remote-server $ logout
Connection to 10.10.10.1 closed.
```

PHP also allows this functionality:

```
user@machine:~/$ cat ssh.php
<?php

passthru("ssh remote-user@10.10.10.1");
```